# Laptop battery flashing

Tags: battery

I got a DELL D505 battery and when in the laptop the light for the battery charging indicator flashes 4 times red and 1 time green.

When I take the battery out and I press the button next to the 5 leds only the first, third and fifth led start flashing. What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only the first, third, and fifth led lights up, it's an indication that the
battery is defective and should be replaced. It's a status message.

Answer (score 0):

These are some form of warning or status message.

You need to find a reference/support doc for this particular battery that tells you want this particular sequence means - I'm having a search now for you, but I'm going out shortly so if someone else finds one please stick up an answer!